# DataContext binding in Page's Resources

Tags: wpf, data-binding, resources, datacontext

I have a page that gets a datacontext objet in the behind code.
I would like to set an empty value to the TextList[11] when the Trigger variable loses the 1 value. The Trigger "int" and the TextList "ObservableCollection" are booth situated in the Datacontext object. The TextList is initialized 20pcs element before set the page datacontext. I have to solve it in wpf code, code behind excluded. My English is pretty poor, sorry!

```
<Page x:Class="LayerTemplates.Templates.example"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LayerTemplates.Templates"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title=""
  xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type System:String}">
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Trigger}" Value="1">
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Page.DataContext" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TextList[11]" Duration="1">
                                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value=""></DiscreteStringKeyFrame>
                            </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    ...
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide a text box or label try to use style triggers instead. As you are setting the value of a string to an empty value I think you might be able to use `Visibility="Hidden"`.

In this example I hide the the label by default but whenever the `MyIntProperty` becomes 1 I change visibility to Visible.

My xaml code looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="TestBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding MyTextProperty}">
        <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyIntProperty}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

Data binding class and codebehind looks like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int MyIntProperty { get; set; } = 1;
    public string MyTextProperty { get; set; } = "This is my text";
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MyViewModel model;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        model = new MyViewModel();
        this.DataContext = model;
    }
}
```

Note that in order to get the visibility to update automatically you have let the view model class implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the `MyIntProperty`.

Comment: I don't want hide. I want: if the Trigger is receiving 1 value then the TextList[11] is receiving an empty string (from wpf code) also the same time.

Comment: I am still not sure if I understand. Perhaps you could post an example which is simpler, instead of a snippet from the actual working project? And/or provide some code from the databound object.